# How to properly redirect in ui-router using conditional routing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using conditional routing in ui-router angular js but cant seem to redirect :
Code:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
  })


  .state('app.login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html'
      }
    }
  })

 .state('app.trial', {
    url: '/trial',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/trial.html'
      }
    },
    resolve:{
      factory: checkRouting
    }


  });
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/therapist');

var checkRouting= function ($q, $location,$state) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();


         if(1==1){
          $location.url('/');
          deferred.reject();

          // $state.go("app.login");

         }else{
              deferred.resolve(true);
         }


    return deferred.promise();

};
```

I tried using state.go as well as location.url but both doesnt seem to work.Tried seeing similar questions but couldnt figure out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should move `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/therapist');` outside of the `.state`.

```
  .state('app.trial', {
    url: '/trial',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/trial.html'
      }
    },
    resolve: {
      factory: checkRouting
    }
  });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/therapist');
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This was an editing mistake while writing copying code on stackoverflow .My code already was as you mentioned in your answer and still I was getting the error

Comment: Is it still cannot redirect or it has others error? Did you try  `debugger;`?